# Screencapture command-line video recording with stop bar in menu bar?

Tags: macos, command-line, screen-capture

Is it possible to create a command-line to start a screencapture recording that also provides the stop button in the menu bar?

```
screencapture -v out.mov
```

I'd like to replace pressing CTRL+SHIFT+5. =)